# Content aggregator for delivering Drupal 8 and CiviMail

Tags: tokens, drupal-8

There were at least two solutions for this in D7, Eileen's [CiviToken extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) and Pogstone's [Content Token extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/content-tokens)

Wondering if anyone has used or knows of something that will provide this for D8.

Goal is to be able to aggregate content (eg based on publish date and a tag) such that Mailings can be sent out with simply a token which then delivers the content in to the mailer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at this extenion: https://github.com/bjendres/de.systopia.newsstore

It can collect/aggregate content in CiviCRM, e.g. from a RSS feed. Those items can then be sent out with CiviMail. With some additional extensions you could even sent them out automatically.

I do not remember all the details and documentation is a bit sparse but probably artfulrobot could help you as he developed most of it.

Comment: Yes, newsstore and newsstoremailer, which made sure no mailings were sent if there was no new content and dealt with templating the emails. RSS was implemented but was designed to take feeds from other sources. But it's not exactly what you wanted, it's not a token provider.

Comment: it may not provide token but it does v much sound like it could deliver the required. thank you both